# Converting unformatted Excel to XML

Tags: xml, excel

I am familiar with converting a normal excel table to xml, which is pretty much a flat structure. My problem is that my table has headers that span all the table columns. I cannot map my Schema to the Cells. The months are automatically added to the cost node as a new row. See example.

Cost    Sale    Profit
      January
100 150 50
20      40  20
      February
100 150 50
20  40  20
      March
100 150 50
20  40  20

This is the XML Result I am looking for

```
<Sales>  
 <Period>  
   <Month>January</Month>  
   <Cost>100</Cost>  
   <Sell>150</Sell>  
   <Profit>50</Profit>  
  </Period>  
  <Period>  
   <Month>February</Month>  
   <Cost>100</Cost>  
   <Sell>150</Sell>  
   <Profit>50</Profit>  
  </Period>  
  <Period>  
   <Month>March</Month>  
   <Cost>100</Cost>  
   <Sell>150</Sell>  
   <Profit>50</Profit>  
 </Period>  
</Sales>
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Comment: Where is the converter to get the Tag "Period"?  How is the converter to know that the 20-40-20 rows are not to be output?  It would be easy to create some bespoke code to create the XML you seek but I do not see how any general routine could produce this XML from this input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much you can adapt your source-excel sheet and if you can post-process the XML-file.

You could insert a helper-column that 'carries over' the month, althoug this would not help you to get rid of the month-entires entirely.

[image]

With this I get the following XML-export.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Sales xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Period>
    <Month>January</Month>
    <Cost>January</Cost>
</Period>
<Period>
    <Month>January</Month>
    <Cost>100</Cost>
    <Sell>150</Sell>
    <Profit>50</Profit>
</Period>
<Period>
    <Month>January</Month>
    <Cost>20</Cost>
    <Sell>40</Sell>
    <Profit>20</Profit>
</Period>
[...]
</Sales>
```

You could then post-process this export with an appropriate XSLT to eliminate the month-only lines. Or go even further with the helper-columns so that the month-only lines will be all empty (i.e. calculate a 2 month-column and a cost-column that has only numeric values). But I can't see a way to eliminate these lines altogether.

HTH Andreas